# How properly insert JavaScript code in to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, web

I have a PHP based website. I need to add a JavaScript code in to the head. I would like to include the code in to a small JavaScript file and call it from within PHP page. The code starts with `<script type="text/javascript">` and ends with `</script>`. So I tried to save the code in to code.js and in the head of my website's PHP code I put `<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js" />` but it didn't work. I am wondering what am I doing wrong?

The content of the PHP page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title of the page</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--head-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
    <body>
        <!----start-wrap---->
    <div class="wrap">
        <!----start-Header---->
    <!----End-Logo---->
            <!--body-top-->
            code of the huge page
    <!----End-wrap---->
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to insert the following JavaScript code instead of the `<!--head-->`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _prvar=_prvar||new Object();
    (function(pa,s){if(document.getElementById('125456'))return false;
    pa=document.createElement('script');pa.type='text/javascript';pa.async=true;pa.id='125456';pa.src='//abcdefg.com/pub.js';
    s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa,s);})();
</script>
```

So what I did is placed the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _prvar=_prvar||new Object();
    (function(pa,s){if(document.getElementById('125456'))return false;
    pa=document.createElement('script');pa.type='text/javascript';pa.async=true;pa.id='125456';pa.src='//abcdefg.com/pub.js';
    s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa,s);})();
</script>
```

in to a code.js and instead of the `<!--head-->`in the PHP code I inserted `<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js" />`

Comment: simply use echo "<scriptt> ........</script>" ; in the right place

Comment: Are you trying to execute Javascript server side? Unless you're using a server-side implementation of JS, you can't. That's not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have inserted the tag script as a non-templated tag, here is the right form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
```

Obviously, if the .js is located in the right place, it will be loaded.

You haven't seen the tag in your code probably because you've inspected the HTML with an HTML inspector, but that tool is not always capable to show you malformed tags. For be sure to see the right HTML result, you must view the souce code (usually, right click on the web page via browser and "show source code" option is there).

Comment: It's still not working. I replaced the closing tag as Sycraw suggested.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried to put some dumb text in your php to see if it appears when you reload the page?

Comment: Obviously, I mean inside the body of HTML and only if you can do it without facing the website to the world :) @MichaelAlbertson

Answer (score 0):

The content of the php page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title of the page</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--head-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
    <body>
        <!----start-wrap---->
    <div class="wrap">
        <!----start-Header---->
    <!----End-Logo---->
            <!--body-top-->
            code of the huge page
    <!----End-wrap---->
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to insert the following javascript code instead of the `<!--head-->` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _prvar=_prvar||new Object();
    (function(pa,s){if(document.getElementById('125456'))return false;
    pa=document.createElement('script');pa.type='text/javascript';pa.async=true;pa.id='125456';pa.src='//abcdefg.com/pub.js';
    s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa,s);})();
</script>
```

So what I did is placed the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _prvar=_prvar||new Object();
    (function(pa,s){if(document.getElementById('125456'))return false;
    pa=document.createElement('script');pa.type='text/javascript';pa.async=true;pa.id='125456';pa.src='//abcdefg.com/pub.js';
    s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa,s);})();
</script>
```

in to a code.js and instead of the `<!--head-->`in the php code I inserted `<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js" />`